# AJAX call is not working in Codeigniter and how to reload page / refire ajax conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to check the status of a transaction with some remote server using their API. What I want is that as a result of my ajax call, if I get 1 or 4 as response from the contoller, the current page/view should be reloaded and ajax should stop firing, otherwise the same ajax should be re-fired after every 5 seconds until I get 1 or 4 as a response from the contoller.

> Note: The values 1 and 4 are being returned from the model function
>   named *fetchdetails* to the controller function.

Following is my Controller function code:

```
$data["pdstat"]=$this->public_m->fetchdetails($paymentid);
echo json_encode(array('resp'=>$data["pdstat"]));
```

Following is the code inside my view:

```
echo "<div class='alert alert-primary'>Please wait. Verification under process.</div>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    var recall = function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                        url: '".base_url()."PDetails/".$this->session->payment_id."',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(res){
                        if(res) {
                            var rcode=0;
                            var len=res.length;
                            for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
                            {
                                rcode=res[i]['resp'];
                            }
                            if(rcode=='1' || rcode=='4')
                            {
                                console.log('reloading');
                                window.location = window.location.href;
                            }
                            else if(rcode=='3' || rcode=='5')
                            {
                                console.log('recalling');
                                recall();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log('recalling');
                        recall();
                        }
                        },
                        error: function(res, status, error) {
                            var err = res.responseText;
                            console.log(res.Message);
                            console.log(status);
                            console.log(error);
                            console.log('recalling');
                               recall();
                        }
                    });
        };
    recall();
  </script>";
```

I have inspected the page and checked Console and Network tabs. The ajax call has not been initiated at all.

Comment: Negative marking to the question within 1 minute of posting it? Can you please explain the reason of negative marking this question?

Comment: Calling JS between PHP with `echo`. It's strange

Comment: @DanishAli Actually there are 4-5 conditionals out of which in 3 I need to call this script, so I kept it inside echo. Will it create a problem?

Comment: I don't think so. Also, it is very bad way to do this

Comment: you need to add document ready, and double check that there are no errors/the script is getting outputted to the page